# How to update other objects in the ObservableCollection<T> on a DataGrid and display in real-time?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I created a `ModelView` class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Then I created a `ObservableCollection<ModelView>` that is bound to the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid`.

Wow that's a lot of boilerplate.  Anyways, with that aside I'm trying to do something that seems super trivial in Windows Forms, but I don't understand how WPF intends us to do this.

Essentially, I have a series of rows and each row can be thought of as a `ModelView` object.  One of the properties (columns) is `Type`, and if I edit any of the other columns I would like in real-time the `DataGrid` to update all the other rows for that column to the same value (for those of the same Type).

Seems like with this model view approach if the notify property change happens and I scan everything inside there than that in turn triggers a property change which triggers another and so on and it's out of control.  So how does WPF handle this sort of thing?

Comment: When you bind an item to a WPF object's property, at runtime, if the bound object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface it subscribes to the PropertyChanged Event. When the event is raised, if the modified property was the one bounded to your object, your object will refresh it's display. Hope it clarified some things.

Comment: Can post a sample which help understand your issue better

Comment: Basically I wanted to iterate over the entire collection and modify attributes based on the edit of a single row.  I ended up doing this by iterating over every object in a method that is invoked by the `CellEditEnding` event on the `DataGrid`.